# Adding elevation data to line using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, line, elevation

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I want to draw a line at the starting and ending of elevation, and then use straight line interpolation to assign the rest of the line an elevation.

Comment: It is not possible!

Answer (score 5):

To achieve this you need 3D Analyst and also elevation model:

```
arcpy.InterpolateShape_3d("DEM", "ROADS", "in_memory/road_3d")
arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management("road_3d", "LINE_START_MID_END")
arcpy.FeatureTo3DByAttribute_3d("road_3d", "in_memory/LINEAR_3D", "START_Z", "END_Z")
```

So for the road shown:

[image]

it will result in:

[image]

Note: If you know elevations at line ends, you'll need just one tool, that is feature to 3d by attribute(s).

This is actually a very primitive way of 'DEM burning' used by many applications.

Comment: So if I have a line, I can create 2 new fields (elevation at start and end of line) and use this to create my line with 3D attributes? How could I then turn that line into say 20 points, with each point containing an elevation value?

Comment: Use feature vertices to points, add Z information. Two tools.